# Android BLE: Set a float to a BluetoothGattCharacteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I have to set a float value to BluetoothGattCharacteristic, for example  [Temperature Measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.temperature_measurement.xml) with the

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT
```

and an offset. I'm not sure if it should be 0 or 1.

The problem is that there is a method for reading a float from a characteristic:
[BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getFloatValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getFloatValue(int,%20int))
but there is no method for setting a float direct!
Some methods which I found and tried:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(byte[])
```

or

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(int mantissa, int exponent, int formatType, int offset)
```

but unfortunatelly when i use these methods, then i cannot read the values by 
using the standard

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getFloatValue()
```

method.

Has someone an idea how to set a float to a characteristic in a way, that I can
read it then with the .getFloatValue() method?